# How to uninitalize UIView?

Tags: swift, uiview, ios8

I want to completely obliterate my UIView after a certain user action. How can I achieve this?

Setting to nil doesn't work.

```
self.myUIView = nil
```

'UIView' does not conform to protocol 'NilLiteralConvertible'

Releasing doesn't work with iOS8.

```
[self.myUIView release]
```

Removing from superview definitely doesn't work.

```
self.myUIView.removeFromSuperview()
```

Comment: Removing from superview doesn't do anything?

Comment: on a memory pointer point of view.

Answer (score 1):

If you intend on setting your property `myUIView` to nil, then it should be declared as optional:

```
var myUIView : UIView?
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare your `UIView` property as `weak`, so that the property does not increase the object's reference count. Once you remove it from its superview, the object should have a reference count of 0, at which point it should be deallocated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not supposed to manually release something in ARC
and the only circumstance you should consider problems about proper releasing is when 'strong reference circle' occurs.

Comment: ARC strictly prohibits you from calling `-[NSObject release]`.

Comment: @influxd I'm sorry i missed some words and please see the new edit :)